# GitOps & Infrastrucute as a Code - secrets storing

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, gitlab, terraform, hashicorp-vault

Just conceptual questions because I apparently doesn't feel the articles already available @google in this topic.

**The story:**

I have 2 git projects for `IaC` which create and configure network and create and configure projects. Both of those projects use different service accounts to perform operation on the cloud (different permissions are needed by them and I don't want to have one super account with all permissions). I would like to perform `CICD` pipeline which will allow to perform in general `teraform apply`.

***The question:***

I would like to not store keys for such accounts at `GitLab` (gitlab variables - I would like to store them in `Hashicorp Vault` - **The goal is to make sure that it will only be avaliable for CICD**. No human should be allowed to access those keys. ***How to make it work?*** To `cloud access keys` stored at vault I still need `vault key` to be stored on runner machine or in gitlab variables both not considered as safe for me, if anyone will get access to `vault key` it is really easy to access `service account keys` by `Vault Rest API`

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow you - your goal is to have a service that will allow ONLY service accounts to access the keys? So that no human, even the project owner, can see them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way we solve this is by leveraging Gitlab’s identities and Vault’s JWT authentication method.

You can read more about this here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/authenticating-with-hashicorp-vault/ for Gitlab and https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/jwt for the Vault auth method.

Why would this solve the issue (if I understood your challenge correctly)?

Once you have this setup, you can

- create an identity entity in Vault to represent your CI service account
- create an alias to bind this identity entity to the identity Gitlab will provide in CI_JOB_JWT
- create a policy to allow this identity entity (directly or via a group) to read the secrets)

Hence anyone running the pipeline from another identity won’t be able to read the secrets (because it would map to another identity entity in Vault, so they won’t get a token with that policy)